# dBASE VS Python/Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, web-applications, dbase

A manager at work wants my team to use *[dBASE](http://www.dbase.com/dbasesql/features/)* instead of Python/Postgres for an upcoming web application project. I know dBASE is obsolete, but that by itself isn't convincing enough, since another (unrelated) department has been running it for decades.

The [database comparison charts](http://db-engines.com/en/system/PostgreSQL%3BdBASE) that I found are slightly out of date, or don't mention dBASE at all.

Wikipedia, blogs, and the official marketing page say that dBASE supports SQL, ODBC, that the language is object oriented, and that it can be used to develop web applications.

Can anyone offer any sort of apples to apples comparison of features, performance, reliability, X, between dBASE and Postgres (or even MySQL)?

Can anyone offer a factual explanation of why dBASE isn't a viable solution for modern web applications?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get a complete (!) list of requirements for your database and then start searching for a solution. One of my requirements would be where to find people who can handle dBase. The '80's are over, dBase is over.....

Comment: Maybe show your manager this presentation about modern SQL: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2015-02/modern-sql  There is [another DBMS comparison](http://www.sql-workbench.net/dbms_comparison.html) where I would expect dBase to have a `NO` for nearly every feature in that list

Answer (score 0):

Although dBase is over, and so too (for the most part) is Visual FoxPro (VFP), there are still people out there using it.  It is good in that it does not require a "SERVER" based solution as it has it's own much like others that run based on a dll (such as SQLite, Advantage Database and others).

To help you in your argument, and not knowing the facts...

Consider that the file limits are probably still that of a maximum of 2 gig per single file, not entire database, but single file as that is the max of 32-bit systems when dBase (and VFP) were created.

Yes, it can be a fast engine, but what sort of volume / activity are you going to be hit with.  As Frank mentioned, where are you going to find someone with strong knowledge with the language, let alone implementing it to the web expertise.  So, unless you have it in-house it might be a chore.

What happens for any database table corruptions, which is going to be more reliable and recoverable if there IS an issue.

So, just a few things I would consider to pass on to mgmt.

Answer (score 0):

I've read your question. One of my first projects was in VFP, it was an accounting system (now defunct), and the absolute paramount critical thing you ought to ask is "Why" - Here's why I stopped using it. (1) not scalable, (2) data integrity, (3) ease of hacking, (4) ancient technology, (5) limited "live" resources to help with technology if run into any problems (and you will), (6) no longer supported by the vendor...